# ¿Se puede aplicar o llamar una función en el parámetro "periods" de la función date_range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Quiero aplicar un date_range al índice de mi dataframe que viene como datetime, para la cual deseo que se sume en dicho indice las horas, días, meses de acuerdo a un valor de hora de duración.

```
Ej: Dataframe Original

  FechaHora_Salida       Hora_Duración
2020-04-10 06:19:45            3
2020-04-19 20:05:50            6
2020-04-30 22:50:00            4

Ej: Resultado Deseado del Dataframe

 FechaHora_Salida       Hora_Duración
2020-04-10 06:19:45            3
2020-04-19 07:19:45            3
2020-04-19 08:19:45            3
2020-04-19 20:05:50            6
2020-04-19 21:05:50            6
2020-04-19 22:05:50            6
2020-04-19 23:05:50            6
2020-04-20 00:05:50            6
2020-04-20 01:05:50            6
2020-04-30 22:50:00            4
2020-04-30 23:50:00            4
2020-05-01 00:50:00            4
2020-05-01 01:50:00            4
```

¿Qué solución me recomiendan? ¿Se puede aplicar una función en el parametro "periodo" del date_range?

Answer (score 0):

Primero voy a **replicar tu problema**:

```
FechaHora_Salida = pd.date_range("1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", freq="h")
Hora_Duración = np.random.randint(100, 5000, 25)
df_horas = pd.DataFrame({"FechaHora_Salida":FechaHora_Salida,
                         "Hora_Duración":Hora_Duración})
```

Genial, ahora tenemos un `DataFrame` con las horas del uno de enero de 2020. (He puesto muchas horas para que en el resultado se aprecien las diferencias)

```
                    Hora_Duración
2020-01-01 00:00:00 0
2020-01-01 01:00:00 12
2020-01-01 02:00:00 24
2020-01-01 03:00:00 36
2020-01-01 04:00:00 48
...           ...       ...
```

### Solución

Partiendo de esto podemos ir aplicando la función `pd.Timedelta()` esta función nos convierte las horas a un objeto `Timedelta` que nos permite poder operar con los objetos `timestamp`, con el parámetro `hours` de dicha función le indicamos que **le vamos a pasar horas**, la solución sería:

```
df_horas["horas_add"] = df_horas.apply(lambda row: row[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=row[1]), axis=1)
```

**Salida:**

```
                 Hora_Duración   horas_add
2020-01-01 00:00:00 0   2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-01-01 01:00:00 12  2020-01-01 13:00:00
2020-01-01 02:00:00 24  2020-01-02 02:00:00
2020-01-01 03:00:00 36  2020-01-02 15:00:00
2020-01-01 04:00:00 48  2020-01-03 04:00:00
...           ...                 ...
```

**¿Qué está sucediendo?**

1. Con el método `.apply()` y su parámetro `axis=1` lo que hacemos es iterar por cada fila del *DataFrame*.
2. `lambda row: row[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=row[1])` nos hemos creado una función `lambda` que toma una fila y retorna la operación de sumar el indice de dicha fila con la primera columna (Hora_Duración)
3. `df_horas["horas_add"]`: por último almacenamos el resultado en una nueva columna (esto ya es opcional, puedes almacenarlo como tu quieras).

El mayor truco junto con `pd.Timedelta()` está en saber que puedes seleccionar el indice de una fila al usar el método `apply()` consultado el atributo `.name`.

Comment: Gracias Alberto por tu gran aporte, duda: ¿En que punto de la función `lambda row: row[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=row[1])` se esta tomando la **Hora_Duración**, no lo veo o entiendo correctamente.

Comment: Adicional a lo anterior, como verás en mi dataframe original, necesito que parezca la traza de la Hora de Duración, por ejemplo; la FechaHora_Salida fue a la 01:00:00 con Hora de Duración 4 Horas, el resultado debería ser 01:00:00 (1era fila), 02:00:00 (2da fila), 03:00:00 (3era fila) y 04:00:00 (4ta fila). ¿Como integro la función repeat() a tu solución parcial? Gracias.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta pidiendo esta información, no es sencillo darse cuenta a partir del ejemplo. También aprovecha por favor y añade lo que tú has intentado, esto siempre es de ayuda. En cuanto lo tengas intento darte una solución y una explicación más detallada! :)

Comment: Hola Alberto, no es necesario editar la pregunta. Se ve a detalle el resultado que coloque en el punto **"Ej: Resultado Deseado del Dataframe"**, donde se ve que suma la hora, día y mes de la primera columna en base a la Hora de Duración. En dicho resultado deseado; se ve a detalle como se suman y genera la traza de las horas, días y mes en las filas posteriores, no en las columnas adicionales. Tu solución me da una idea, lo que hice es agregar este método `df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, abs(viajes['Hora_Duracion']))` para repetir las filas de acuerdo a la hora de duración pero no resulta.